# Imprimir mais de 1 valor java

Tags: java

Estou estudando matrizes. A matriz consta em informações de personagens do game of thrones. Minha matriz:

```java
public static String [][] matrizPrincipal() {
        String [] [] matriz = new String [6] [114];
        matriz[0][0] = "Robin Arryn";
        matriz[1][0] = "Lino Facioli";
        matriz[2][0] = "145";
        matriz[3][0] = "Vivo";
        matriz[4][0] = "Arryn";
        matriz[5][0] = "Masculino";

        matriz[0][1] = "Yohn Royce";
        matriz[1][1] = "Rupert Vansittart";
        matriz[2][1] = "45";
        matriz[3][1] = "Vivo";
        matriz[4][1] = "Arryn";
        matriz[5][1] = "Masculino";
        return matriz;
    }
```

Sim, ela não está completa.

```
Linha 0: Nome Personagem
Linha 1: Ator
linha 2: Temporadas que participa
Linha 3: Vivo ou morto
Linha 4: Família
Linha 5: Genero
```

Estou com problemas no método que retorna o personagem de uma determinada temporada. O usuário digita a temporada desejada, e o método irá imprimir todos os personagens atuantes na mesma. Tenho o método pronto já, só estou com problema na hora do retorno.

Método:

```java
public static String imprimeMatrizQualTemporada(String temporada, String [] [] mat) {
    for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++) {
            if(mat[2][j].contains(temporada)) {
                System.out.println(mat[0][j] + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return "Não encontramos um personagem com este nome";
}
```

A String temporada e String mat vem do método principal, onde temporada é a temporada que o cara quer saber quais personagens estão.

Na hora de compilar o método acima, sem problemas, porém na hora de executar tenho o seguinte erro:

[image: Erro na hora de executar]

O mais bizarro, é que apesar do erro ele retorna o resultado certinho:

[image: Resultado sendo exibido]

Só não sei o porque deste erro, que aponta para o seguinte if:

```java
if(mat[2][j].contains(temporada)) {
    System.out.println(mat[0][j] + "\n");
}
```

De uma coisa eu tenho certeza. Tem a ver com esse `System.out.println`, pois quando eu tento fazer do seguinte modo:

```java
if(mat[2][j].contains(temporada)) {
    return mat[0][j];
}
```

Usando `return`, ele funciona perfeitamente, porém só retorna o primeiro personagem, e não todos.

**Atualização:** Código completo abaixo para melhorar a visualização

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class matriz {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("\f");
        String [][] mat = matrizPrincipal();
        System.out.println("1.Listar atores e suas respectivas temporadas.");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String msg = in.nextLine();
        int opcao = Integer.parseInt(msg);        
        switch(opcao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Digite a temporada à se verificar");
                String temporada = in.nextLine();
                String resultado2 = imprimeMatrizQualTemporada(temporada,mat);
                System.out.println("Personagens nesta Temporada:" +resultado2);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static String [][] matrizPrincipal() {
        String [] [] matriz = new String [6] [114];
        matriz[0][0] = "Robin Arryn";
        matriz[1][0] = "Lino Facioli";
        matriz[2][0] = "145";
        matriz[3][0] = "Vivo";
        matriz[4][0] = "Arryn";
        matriz[5][0] = "Masculino";

        matriz[0][1] = "Yohn Royce";
        matriz[1][1] = "Rupert Vansittart";
        matriz[2][1] = "45";
        matriz[3][1] = "Vivo";
        matriz[4][1] = "Arryn";
        matriz[5][1] = "Masculino";
        return matriz;
    }

    public static String imprimeMatrizQualTemporada(String temporada, String [] [] mat) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < mat[i].length; j++){
                if(mat[2][j].contains(temporada)){
                    System.out.println(mat[0][j] + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        return "Não encontramos um personagem com este nome";
    }

}
```

Comment: Coloque o código completo ao invés de pedaços. Fica mais fácil reproduzir e encontrar o erro.

Comment: Pronto! Aidicionei ao post principal

Comment: O código no inicio da sua pergunta, aquele que preenche a matriz, é diferente daquele que você posta na actualização. Qual dos dois é que está a dar os erros?

Comment: Está falando do método da matriz principal? Aqui está igual o.o

Comment: Olhe para a sua pergunta e verificará que não estão iguais

Comment: Bizarro, eu não havia mechido ali. De qualquer maneira ja arrumei..

Comment: Como estava inicialmente eu entendia os erros, com o código actualizado não vejo nada de errado.

Comment: Eu postei o erro que aparece em imagens logo acima. Por isso que eu acho estrnaho, pois ele mostra esse erro http://i.stack.imgur.com/PFPwd.png mas executa perfeitamente o que foi pedido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é devido ao facto de você declarar a matriz como tendo 6 linhas e 114 colunas e apenas atribuir valores para 6 linhas e 2 colunas.

O valor retornado por `mat.length;` é `6` e `mat[i].length;` é `114`.
No decorrer dos dois *loops* `i`e `j` irão apontar para elementos da matriz que não foram inicializados, daí a `NullPointerException`.

Deverá alterar a linha:

```
String [] [] matriz = new String [6] [114];
```

Para:

```
String [] [] matriz = new String [6] [2];
```

Erros à parte, também a sua matriz está mal formada, as suas dimensões deveriam ser invertidas:`[2] [6]`.
Cada personagem devia ser atribuída a uma linha e as suas características atribuídas às colunas.
Por outro lado apenas é necessário um *loop* para obter o resultado que pretende.
Tendo isto em conta o seu código seria assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class matriz {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("\f");
        String [][] mat = matrizPrincipal();
        System.out.println("1.Listar atores e suas respectivas temporadas.");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String msg = in.nextLine();
        int opcao = Integer.parseInt(msg);        
        switch(opcao) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Digite a temporada à se verificar");
                String temporada = in.nextLine();
                String resultado2 = imprimeMatrizQualTemporada(temporada,mat);
                System.out.println("Personagens nesta Temporada:" +resultado2);
                break;
        }
    }

    public static String [][] matrizPrincipal() {
        String [] [] matriz = new String [2] [6];
        matriz[0][0] = "Robin Arryn";
        matriz[0][1] = "Lino Facioli";
        matriz[0][2] = "145";
        matriz[0][3] = "Vivo";
        matriz[0][4] = "Arryn";
        matriz[0][5] = "Masculino";

        matriz[1][0] = "Yohn Royce";
        matriz[1][1] = "Rupert Vansittart";
        matriz[1][2] = "45";
        matriz[1][3] = "Vivo";
        matriz[1][4] = "Arryn";
        matriz[1][5] = "Masculino";
        return matriz;
    }
    public static String imprimeMatrizQualTemporada(String temporada, String [] [] mat) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++) {
            if(mat[i][2].contains(temporada)){
                System.out.println(mat[i][0] + "\n");
            }
        }
        return "Não encontramos um personagem com este nome";
    }
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/lS0ieZ)

Comment: Perfeito era isso mesmo! Defini 114 pois terão ao total 114 linhas, só queria deixar a parte chata para o final rsrs